# How to make page submit on itself

Tags: javascript, php, web, refresh

I am trying to make PHP script, which will submit ID onto itself and want to make auto submit, like refresh which will send data to refreshed page :)Is it posible to use ;URL=''"> this meta refresh

Comment: In order to submit to itself you should use `<form>` without `action` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this;

```
<script> 
    window.onload = function() { 
        setInterval(function(){ 
            document.frm.submit(); 
        },5000); 
    } 
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform" method="post" name="myform">
    <?php $id = $_POST['id']; $id=$id+1; ?> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
</form>
```

This will submit form every 5 secs after page loaded

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/tu4Jg/)**

Comment: Nope. It will refresh, then, if its on the ready event of the document, when it finishes loading will be submited after 5 seconds again.

Comment: I already assumed this interval is starts after page loaded. But, thanks again

Comment: I understand that. But in fact it won't be after exactly 5 secs.

Comment: Will i be able to send ID like That?? `code` <form id="post" method="post"action="">

<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;

 
 $id=$id+1;
  

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>`code`

Comment: No, but I have also added form structure to my answer see my updated answer. JS updated HTML added

Comment: your code doesn't helped me, it doesnot refresh page :)

Comment: May I see your web page? Where did you put js code? I see, your method is POST I have updated code. Use updated code

Comment: I updated and inserted your code.  `code` <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="post" method="post"action="">
    <?php $id = $_POST['id']; $id=$id+1; ?> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/> 
</form>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("post").submit();
    },5000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html> `code` This is my whole code

Comment: And saved this page as php? So, what is your error?

Comment: Yes it is php saxed in xampp/htdocs. my error is that page doesnot refresh automatically.

Comment: Ok, I have updated code and give a demo. Please see updated answer and use updated one